# Equivalent inequality of $\left|\sin^{-1}(x) + \sin^{-1}(y)\right|\le\frac{\pi}{2}$ only in terms of x and y?

Tags: trigonometry, inequality, inverse

I was working with the inequality,
$$\left|\sin^{-1}(x) + \sin^{-1}(y)\right|\le\frac{\pi}{2} , \{|x|,|y|\le1\}.$$

I was trying to find an inequality only in terms of x and y without containing any trigonometric functions. Then after some hit and trial I found following beautiful inequality,
$$\biggl|x|x| + y|y| \biggr|\le 1 , \{|x|,|y|\le1\}.$$
But the problem is I couldn't derive this inequality and couldn't show their equivalence. I know they are equivalent by plotting them in Desmos(Function Plotting Program). Can you derive the proof showing the equivalence of these two inequalities ?

**Note** : The above inequality is the condition for the following relation to satisy,
$$\sin^{-1}(x) + \sin^{-1}(y) = \sin^{-1}\left(x\sqrt{1-y^2} + y\sqrt{1-x^2}\right)$$
I had thought this formula works for every value of $|x|,|y|\le1$ but turns out it doesn't. It only works when x and y satisfy above inequality.

Comment: You shall consider to take the sine of $-\frac{\pi}{2}\leq\sin^{-1}(x)+\sin^{-1}(y)\leq\frac{\pi}{2}$ -- take care of the fact that sine can be non-increasing sometimes. You will have to use $\sin(a+b)=\sin(a)\cos(b)+\sin(b)\cos(a)$ as well as $\cos(\sin^{-1}(a))=\pm\sqrt{1-a^2}$.

Comment: I still can't do anything. Can you please explain with steps ? Actually the first equality was derived from $\sin(a+b) = \sin(a)\cos(b) +sin(b)\cos(a)$ and I don't think proceeding in reverse direction will yield anything.

Comment: $$\left|\sin^{-1}(x) + \sin^{-1}(y)\right|\le\frac{\pi}{2} , \{|x|,|y|\le1\}.$$ is not true.

Comment: It is not a statement. It is a condition which is satisfied by some values of x and y less than 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We need $$\cos(\sin^{-1}x+\sin^{-1}y)\ge0$$

$$\implies\sqrt{(1-x^2)(1-y^2)}\ge xy$$

which is obvious $xy<0$

What if $xy=0?$

If $xy>0,$  $$(1-x^2)(1-y^2)\ge x^2y^2\iff 1\ge x^2+y^2$$

Comment: It worked for xy > 0 but I couldn't understand how does it work for xy < 0.

Comment: @RohitJoshi, As for real $x,y$ with $-1\le x^2,y^2\le1$  $$\sqrt{(1-x^2)(1-y^2)}\ge0$$

Comment: How does this leads to my 2nd inequality ? I want to prove my that 1st inequality implies the 2nd one.

Comment: @RohitJoshi, If $xy<0,$  either  $y<0,x>0$  then $$x|x|+y|y|=x^2-y^2\le1$$ as $$x^2\le1,y^2\ge0$$  Similarly for $x<0,y>0$